# CSS selector for div containing an input with focus

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have a link at the top of a page that when hovered over, displays a search menu.

```css
#dropdown {
  display: none;
}

li:hover #dropdown {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li><a href="">Link 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Link 2</a></li>
  <li>
    <a href="">Search</a>
    <div id="dropdown">
      <input name="txtSearch" type="text" id="txtSearch" class="form-control" />
      <input type="submit" name="btnSearch" value="Search" id="btnSearch" class="btn" />
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Since there is a text box inside the dropdown `<div>`, I want the dropdown to stay visible even while unhovered if the user is typing in the text box.

Is there a pure CSS way to do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add the [`:focus-within` pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-within) to any parent element.

```
li:hover #dropdown,
li:focus-within #dropdown {
  display: block;
}
```

However, keep in mind [this is not supported in Microsoft browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=focus-within). You'll need a JavaScript-based solution for that. Here's one that uses jQuery:

```js
$(document).on('focus','#txtSearch,#btnSearch',function(e) {
   $(this).closest('li').addClass('hover');
}).on('blur','#txtSearch,#btnSearch',function(e) {
   $(this).closest('li').removeClass('hover');
});
```

```css
#dropdown {
  display: none;
}

li:hover #dropdown,
li.hover #dropdown {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li><a href="">Link 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Link 2</a></li>
  <li>
    <a href="">Search</a>
    <div id="dropdown">
      <input name="txtSearch" type="text" id="txtSearch" class="form-control" />
      <input type="submit" name="btnSearch" value="Search" id="btnSearch" class="btn" />
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It's too bad the majority of my users are using IE because that CSS solution is perfect. I'm annoyed I'm going to have to use JS.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `focus-within` pseudoclass here.

[Info from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-within)

[Supported browsers](http://www.caniuse.com/#feat=css-focus-within)

```css
#dropdown {
  display: none;
}

li:hover #dropdown {
  display: block;
}

#dropdown:focus-within {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li><a href="">Link 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Link 2</a></li>
  <li>
    <a href="">Search</a>
    <div id="dropdown">
      <input name="txtSearch" type="text" id="txtSearch" class="form-control" />
      <input type="submit" name="btnSearch" value="Search" id="btnSearch" class="btn" />
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```